# Android - Multiple AppBundle

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I have my own application published on the play store, I release an update with bug fixing and new functionalities every two months more or less.
During one of the last update I found that new functionalities are not suitable for Android < 7.
So I decide to go on with my release update but leaving on the store an old version of the application that the Android 5 and 6 users can still use.
Thus, until few days ago on the play store there were two versions of my application: one for Android 5 and 6 users and one for the ones with Android greater or equal than 7.
Now I published the new updated release target for Android >= 7 but I cannot see anymore the previous version for Android < 7.

Do you know if this behaviour is normal? Should I have to publish again the same version target for And<7 every time I want to publish a new release?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the same application ID for both versions? If so, the newest will replace the another in Google Play.

It'll be harder for you to maintain two applications, so my recommendation is:

1. Add some analytics to your app to check the percentage of your users
   that are still using Android 6 and below. In this case, you can check if
   it is worth the trouble.
2. If that amount of users that are below SDK version 7 is relevant, I'll suggest looking for third-party libraries that add those functionalities you are looking for, most of the newest features can be added using different libraries.

I hope that can have helped you in some way. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

For every release of a new app version, you need to remember to add the AAB targeting Android < 7 in the release in addition to uploading the new AAB targeting 7+.

See the button "Add from library" in the UI.

[image: add from library screenshot]

Comment: Thank you very much @Pierre. Do you have any official documentation where I can find these informations??